# Can I use jQuery( ) as a constructor?

Tags: jquery

Function `jQuery()` is a factory function. Can I use it as a constructor?

```
var ax = jQuery('a');
var bx = new jQuery('a');
```

Do they have the same meaning? The new object inherit whose prototype object?

(I promise: I'll not use it as a constructor in real life)

Comment: It is really hard for me to hold back the -1 because this can be trivially tested and explored. I can only hope it is for the benefit of *others* ..

Comment: @pst I'll not use it as a constructor in real life. I want to know the relations between the new object and `jQuery.prototype`/`jQuery.prototype.init.prototype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference, because all it does is return something:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

If constructors return <del>something else</del> another object, that's what's returned and the constructed object is discarded. So... don't use `new jQuery`! :)

Comment: The new object inherit whose `prototype` object?

Comment: *If constructors return something else* Only if that returned something is an object too.

Comment: @kev: It inherits `jQuery.prototype`, which is the same thing as `jQuery.fn` - but the new object is ignored. `jQuery.fn.init` takes care of the construction.

Comment: @minitech. Do you mean: the returned object inherits `jQuery.fn.init.prototype`?

Comment: @kev: Yup - which is exactly the same as the `jQuery.prototype`/`jQuery.fn`. See these lines in the source: `// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation`
`jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter, as `jQuery()` internally will return a new constructed `jQuery` object.

However, I'd recommend you just use `jQuery()` (without `new` operator).